# Long running sp_server_diagnostics

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

sp_server_diagnostics is running from past 28 days, i.e., from last server reboot. This is going on every month. It never stops and gets notified as long running sessions often. It starts again after monthly windows security updates. Not any noticeable resource consumption from this session. But Why? What's the purpose of this and can we kill it? What's the impact if terminated. We do not see this on any other server. This Prod server is Primary Availability Replica of AlwaysOn AG (2 nodes) Synchronous Replica setup. Thanks

Comment: Quite normal for an AG setup, just ignore it https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/sp_server_diagnostics-process-running-all-the-time

Answer (score 3):

> sp_server_diagnostics is running from past 28 days [...]

That is fine. sp_server_diagnostics is used to return the result set of data which the resource dll (hadrres.dll) will use to determine if the AG is healthy based on the failure condition level for that AG. This means the instance had an AG that was primary for that long. This is how this works and is expected.

> It never stops and gets notified as long running sessions often.

Make an exclusion or something for it, it's a false alert. There are other items on secondary replicas such as `DB STARTUP` which also run for a long time (if there is DML on the primary, consistently) which you may also want to look into excluding.

> But Why? What's the purpose of this and can we kill it?

See above on purpose. Do not attempt to kill it, this is needed for proper AG functionality.

> What's the impact if terminated.

More alerts, but for different reasons.

> We do not see this on any other server.

It only runs on primary replicas. This means none of your other servers host a primary replica.